# Please explain me the query attached

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

Folks,

Can someone please help me to explain the below query?

```
 SELECT   SOME_ID ROOT_CAT,
          CHILD_ID SOME_ID
 FROM    CHILD_TABLE
 START WITH SOME_ID IN (SELECT ROOT_ID FROM ROOT_TABLE)
 CONNECT BY NOCYCLE SOME_ID = PRIOR CHILD_ID;
```

Comment: It's a so-called tree query that fetches hierarchical data. What exactly is your problem with it?

Comment: Look here [START WITH and CONNECT BY in Oracle SQL](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/connect_by.html)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is used for fetching hierarchical data  which is something like **Parent - Child - Child of child** etc.

`start with` -- this identifies all LEVEL=1 nodes in the tree 
`connect by` -- describes how to walk from the parent nodes above to their children and 
their childrens children.

The general syntax is

```
select ... 
start with initial-condition 
connect by nocycle 
recurse-condition
```

The connect by construct establishes the recursion. All records that are part of the next lower hierarchical level are found by having SOME_ID= CHILD_ID.

CHILD_ID   is a value found in the current hierarchical level

Your Query can be analogous to:

```
 SELECT   SOME_ID ROOT_CAT,
          CHILD_ID SOME_ID
 FROM    CHILD_TABLE
 START WITH SOME_ID IN (SELECT ROOT_ID FROM ROOT_TABLE)
 CONNECT BY NOCYCLE SOME_ID = PRIOR CHILD_ID;

 SELECT  PARENT_ID  CURRENT_PARENT,
         CHILD_ID   PARENT_ID_CURRENT_CHILD
 FROM LIST_OF_CHILDREN
 START WITH PARENT_ID IN ( SELECT SOME_RANDOM_PARENT_ID FROM LIST_OF_PARENTS)
 CONNECT BY NOCYCLE  PARENT_ID = PRIOR CHILD_ID
```

Comment: Unfortunately I wont be able to do upvoting as my reputation doesnt allow me to do.